# How do I get SID for the group using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, sid

I want to get the SID of a group by input the group name and it will return the SID. Is there any way to do this using vbscript ? Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WMI for resolving the SID:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

groupname = "..."

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Group WHERE Name='" & groupname & "'"
For Each group In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  sid = group.SID
Next

If Not IsEmpty(sid) Then
  WScript.Echo "Group " & groupname & " has SID " & sid & "."
Else
  WScript.Echo "SID For group " & groupname & " could not be resolved."
End If
```

If you need to convert the binary SIDs used in AD I'd suggest you do something like this:

```
Function DecodeSID(binSID)
  ReDim octets(LenB(binSID))

  'convert binary string to octet array
  For i = 1 To LenB(binSID)
    octets(i-1) = AscB(MidB(binSID, i, 1))
  Next

  'convert octet array to SID string
  sid = "S-" & CStr(octets(0)) & "-" & Octet2Str(Array(octets(2), octets(3), _
        octets(4), octets(5), octets(6), octets(7)))
  For i = 8 To (4 * octets(1) + 4) Step 4
    sid = sid & "-" & OctetArrayToString(Array(octets(i+3), octets(i+2), _
          octets(i+1), octets(i)))
  Next

  DecodeSID = sid
End Function

Function OctetArrayToString(arr)
  v = 0
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    v = v * 256 + arr(i)
  Next
  OctetArrayToString = CStr(v)
End Function
```

For more information on binary SIDs see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/15/89753.aspx).

Comment: Upvote! Thank you Ansgar, I have always wanted a shorter version and the structure of it.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot where I got this but here it is:

```
Set oAD = GetObject(sLDAP) ' sLDAP starts with "LDAP://"    
wscript.echo "SID: " & HexSIDToDec(OctetToHexStr(oAD.Get("objectSid"))))

Function HexSIDToDec(strSID)
    ' Function to convert most hex SID values to decimal format.
    Dim arrbytSID, lngTemp, j
    ReDim arrbytSID(Len(strSID)/2 - 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrbytSID)
        arrbytSID(j) = CInt("&H" & Mid(strSID, 2*j + 1, 2))
    Next
    If (UBound(arrbytSID) = 11) Then
        HexSIDToDec = "S-" & arrbytSID(0) & "-" & arrbytSID(1) & "-" & arrbytSID(8)
        Exit Function
    End If
    If (UBound(arrbytSID) = 15) Then
        HexSIDToDec = "S-" & arrbytSID(0) & "-" & arrbytSID(1) & "-" & arrbytSID(8)
        lngTemp = arrbytSID(15)
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(14)
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(13)
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(12)
        HexSIDToDec = HexSIDToDec & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)
        Exit Function
    End If
    HexSIDToDec = "S-" & arrbytSID(0) & "-" & arrbytSID(1) & "-" & arrbytSID(8)
    lngTemp = arrbytSID(15)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(14)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(13)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(12)
    HexSIDToDec = HexSIDToDec & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)
    lngTemp = arrbytSID(19)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(18)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(17)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(16)
    HexSIDToDec = HexSIDToDec & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)
    lngTemp = arrbytSID(23)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(22)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(21)
    lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(20)
    HexSIDToDec = HexSIDToDec & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)
    If (UBound(arrbytSID) > 23) Then
        lngTemp = arrbytSID(27)
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(26)
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(25)
        lngTemp = lngTemp * 256 + arrbytSID(24)
        HexSIDToDec = HexSIDToDec & "-" & CStr(lngTemp)
    End If
End Function

Function OctetToHexStr(ByVal arrbytOctet)
    ' Function to convert OctetString (byte array) to Hex string.
    Dim k
    OctetToHexStr = ""
    For k = 1 To Lenb(arrbytOctet)
        OctetToHexStr = OctetToHexStr & Right("0" & Hex(Ascb(Midb(arrbytOctet, k, 1))), 2)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This works only for SIDs of AD objects, and also assumes that a binary SID will be no longer than 28 bytes, which may not always be true. For more information about the structure of binary SIDs see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/15/89753.aspx).