# Convert String to SID without Win32-Query

Tags: c#, vbscript, converters, sid

There is a way to convert the SID into a human readable string, there are many useful posts on stack. 
But is there also a way in the other direction? 
To convert a string into an SID?

The background is I want to add DCOM user, but the rule is written in SDDL-syntax. I understood the SDDL-syntax for the rights, but I wasn't able to find a way to convert my string "group" in an SID `3-445-33445-34` (for example).

Is there maybe a function in VBScript or something else?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081984/how-do-i-get-sid-for-the-group-using-vbscript) but the solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

> `strComputer = "."`
>   `strGroup = "GroupName"`
>   `strDomain = "DomainName"`
>   `Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")`
>   `Set objAccount = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Group.Name='" & strGroup &"',Domain='"& strDomain &"'")`
>   `MSGBOX objAccount.SID`